# How to backup Oracle database from server

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, backup

I connect to Oracle database server for backup database (.dmp file) to my computer with windows command line 
I use syntax

```
expdp myuser/1234@[server_ip]:[serverport]/listener directory=my_data_pump_dir dumpfile=my_pump_backup.dmp nologfile=Y full=y
```

But Error message

> Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
>   ORA-39001: invalid argument value
>   ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
>   ORA-31641: unable to create dump file "C:\app\User\admin\orcl\dpdump_DIR\my_pump_backup.dmp"
>   ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
>   OSD-04002: unable to open file
>   O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.

What should I do?

Comment: **"What should I do?"**  - supply correct path

Comment: check permissions to create files along this path. `select directory_name, directory_path  from dba_directories
where directory_name='MY_DATA_PUMP_DIR'`